# What role do quantized vortices play from the Superfluid model in Superfluid Vacuum Theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, vortex, superfluidity

When rotating a superfluid (such as $^{4}$He) below its critical temperature, sometimes quantized vortices pop up, depending how fast one rotates this superfluid. In the [SVT model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superfluid_vacuum_theory), they propose that the vacuum may be some type of superfluid (it's all a bit speculative). Assuming that this is true, and that the Universe is rotating, then quantum vortices should pop up. What role would they then have in this model?

Sources for those that want to know a bit more:

Quantum Vortices: https://www.physics.umd.edu/courses/Phys726/The_Quantum_Vortex.htm

SVT : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superfluid_vacuum_theory

Comment: could you provide links/sources for the topics mentioned for those who are not familiar with the subject?

Comment: While I cant vouch for the answer, see [mfc](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/153807/what-is-the-point-of-the-reduced-plancks-constant-hbar-h-bar-why-dont) "This is normal if we consider quantum vacuum as a superfluid and fermions as quantum vortices in this superfluid as it happens in other superfluids" but also Michael Porter [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/422371/holographic-superfluid-space-time-and-temperature) on SVT

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much anything and everything from subatomic particles to Black holes. [SVT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superfluid_vacuum_theory) would be the Theory of Everything giving also answers to Dark Energy, Dark matter and quantum gravity as our visible Universe being defects of an omnipresent superfluid medium that we call "Vacuum Space". However, many physicists do not regard the fabric of spacetime being a medium. SVT has to be proven.